# Installing Scapy on Android

Tags: python, android, scapy

I did an installation on android using the follow commands on android:

```
apt install python

pip install scapy
```

everything is fine for now, but when i run scapy i got this error -----see error

This error does not happen to me in conda or kali, it appears to be exclusive for android.

```
ERROR: Loading module scapy.layers.netflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/main.py", line 143, in _load
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/init.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/layers/netflow.py", line 112, in <module>
    class NetflowRecordV5(Packet):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/layers/netflow.py", line 127, in NetflowRecordV5
    ByteEnumField("prot", IP_PROTOS["tcp"], IP_PROTOS),
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/dadict.py", line 49, in getitem
    return getattr(self, attr)
AttributeError: 'DADict' object has no attribute 'tcp'
```

The android device is rooted. I hope someone is familiar with this error and can help. Thanks

Comment: This looks like it could be a bug with Scapy. I would [create an issue](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues) on Scapy's repo, as they will be *best* able to assist with this. If you do create an issue, please post a link to it in a comment or in your question for future readers.

Comment: I almost forget, im using TERMUX for install scapy on android

Answer (score -2):

i did this on my phone but it looks require root access